# Linked list of "random" values, program hangs

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm trying to learn C a little bit and am dealing with linked lists right now. I have defined a linked list as:

```
struct data {
    int xVal;
    int yVal;
    struct data *next;
};
```

What I want to do is insert `num` pairs of values into the linked list, but each pair must be unique.

```
void addToList(num) {
    srand(time(NULL));
    struct data *list = NULL;
    list = malloc(sizeof(struct data));
    struct data *q = list;
    list->xVal = rand() % 100;
    list->yVal = rand() % 100;
    int j = 0;
    while (j < num-1) {
        q->next = malloc(sizeof(struct data));
        q->next->xVal = rand() % 100;
        q->next->yVal = rand() % 100;
        if (unique(list, q->next->xVal, q->next->yVal)) {
            q = q->next;
            j++;
        }
    }
}

bool unique(struct data *list, int x, int y) {
    struct data *q = list;
    while (q->next != NULL) {
        if (q->xVal = x && q->yVal == y) { return false; }
        q = q->next;
    }
    return true;
}
```

What it does is it generates a random value 1-100 for both `xVal` and `yVal`, checks if that pair already exists in the list, and if not it inserts at the end. It compiles fine, but running the program makes it hang. I don't see any infinite loops here. I've tried with `num` equal to 2 and it still hangs.

Removing the check for unique values lets me fill and print the list, but I still run into an exception "Access violation reading location 0xCDCDCDD9.".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem**

You have a logic error.

You add couple of values to the list using:

```
    q->next->xVal = rand() % 100;
    q->next->yVal = rand() % 100;
```

and then check whether they exist in the list. Of course they do. The return value from `unique` is always `false`. As a consequence, `j` never gets incremented and the list keeps growing despite `j` not being incremented.

**Fix**

1. Get the random numbers.
2. Check whether they are unique before adding them to the list.

Here's how I see it.

```
void addToList(num) {
   srand(time(NULL));
   struct data *list = NULL;
   list = malloc(sizeof(struct data));
   struct data *q = list;
   list->xVal = rand() % 100;
   list->yVal = rand() % 100;
   int j = 0;
   while (j < num-1) {
      int x = rand() % 100;
      int y = rand() % 100;
      if ( unique(list, x, y) ) {
         q->next = malloc(sizeof(struct data));
         q->next->xVal = x;
         q->next->yVal = y;
         q->next->next = NULL; // Make sure the list has a clean end
         q = q->next;
         j++;
      }
   }
}
```

And ...

You also have a typo in `unique`.

```
    if (q->xVal = x && q->yVal == y) { return false; }
```

should be:

```
    if (q->xVal == x && q->yVal == y) { return false; }
             // ^^ Need to compare, not assigh.
```